# Threeejs loaded FBX not show all model part

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, fbx

I need your hand. I am importing FBX models into Threejs here the import code:

```
let loader = new FBXLoader();
loader.load(model.obj_path, object => {
  let mix = new THREE.AnimationMixer(object);
  if (object.animations.length) {
     var action = mix.clipAction(
        object.animations[0]
     );
     mixer.push(mix);
     action.play();
  }
  object.castShadow = true;
  object.scale.copy(model.scale);
  object.position.copy(model.position);
  object.rotation.set(model.rotation.x, model.rotation.y, model.rotation.z);
  group.add(object);
  loadingScreen();
}, onProgress);
```

Currently it does not give any import problems, however I realized that for some models, there is a display problem, some parts are missing. Here the screen:

[image: Showed Model]
In this project, however, I also installed the OrbitControl to manage the camera and I found that by moving the camera, zooming and other things, the model becomes complete

[image: Model after move]

I would like to know if this has already happened to someone and if there are ways to fix this. Thanks a lot to everyone and have a good day!

Comment: Interesting. Any chances to demonstrate this issue with an [editable live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)? Or maybe as a git repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be related to frustum culling. Objects that are animated often have badly defined bounding boxes. If the model only appears when its center point goes into the camera field of view, that's an indication that it might be a bounding box problem.